# Measuring execution time of many methods

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I work in project in WPF which uses Entity Framework with SQL Server. The optimalization there is crap. Everything is too slow. And I want to diagnose which parts of code kills the performance - I think that there are only few(I mean many, but not all) places which are poorly designed and kills performance.

Now for every table we have class, for example `UserRepository`. It is not exactly the repository pattern. Those classes has methods like: `GetAll(...), GetById(...), GetNewest(...), GetAllWithHigherSalaryThan(int salary, int companyId)`, and so on, many method accessors to db. Database is used only in repository classes.

I don't want to talk here about refactoring. I just want to measure how long does every method executes and how many times was it executed during runtime. By those information I will be able to find bugs.

I want to measure about 100~ methods which have "selects from db" in many classes.
SQL Server Profiler doesn't do the trick because those methods are executed countless times and analysing logs from profiler is nightmare if possible at all with our approach to database.

Sample method:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoo(int y, int z)
{
    return Context.Where(p =>
        p.X == null &&
        p.Y == y &&
        p.Time >= z).OrderBy(x => x.Time).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Now I was thinking about adding stopwatch to every method, measuring execution time, counting executions and pass it to some singleton or something, then display it. Of course I will turn off this diagnostic when I'm done with it, but this approach is very week course I need to edit every method and I don't know how to turn it off after - I mean I know that I can use something like `#define DEBUG` but it is lame anyway.

I was trying to figure something out with Reflections but with no effects... maybe there is a way to see execution time of methods in C#?

What do you recommend?

Comment: have you tried using the VS profiler, it's pretty good in VS2012 and above?

Comment: Have you looked at [Entity Framework Profiler?](http://www.efprof.com) Pretty nifty piece of software, I must say!

Answer (score 5):

My first recommendation is a proper profiler, my fav is dotTrace from Jetbrains, but there are others.

If somehow that is not an option and you insist to do it yourself:

I recommend Postsharp - or another AOP package. What it can do is add aspects to many methods easily.

With Postsharp you write an aspect:

```
[Serializable] 
public class TraceAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect 
{ 
    public override void OnEntry( MethodExecutionArgs args ) 
    { 
        // start measuring time here
    } 

    public override void OnExit( MethodExecutionArgs args ) 
    { 
        // stop measuring here 
    } 
}
```

Then you apply that aspect to a bunch of methods (all public methods from MyNamespace):

```
#if DEBUG 
[assembly: Trace( AttributeTargetTypes = "MyNamespace.*", 
    AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, 
    AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public )] 
#endif
```

This is all code the needed to instrument many methods at once.

I recently did just that, I dumped all measurements into the csv text file, then dumped that into SQL Server and there I could easily do selects and group by, for example to find out the total time consumed by a method. I was not using a profiler because I did that measurements in production environment - the performance hit from the instrumentation was not much of an impact (if the program is slow anyway).

Here's more info on that:
http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/logging

And even the free version of that - PostSharp Express - is enough to do that.

Comment: I like this clean approach. I've also used an approach with a wrapper method that does the same thing, but it was part of a logging framework which then logged the execution times and other data into a database. Here, I think your approach fits very well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in profiler to the language itself. Your IDE/Debugger *may* have some built-in profiler though, if you don't mind specifying what you're using.

If you're running MSSQL as indicated, you might not be profiling in a way that works for ya. Here's two queries which have worked magically for me:

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
 ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
 WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
 ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
 END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
 qs.execution_count,
 qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
 qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
 qs.total_worker_time,
 qs.last_worker_time,
 qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
 qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
 qs.last_execution_time,
 qp.query_plan
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
 ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
 -- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
 -- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

[source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
 t.TEXT QueryName,
 s.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
 s.max_elapsed_time AS MaxElapsedTime,
 ISNULL(s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count, 0) AS AvgElapsedTime,
 s.creation_time AS LogCreatedOn,
 ISNULL(s.execution_count / DATEDIFF(s, s.creation_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS FrequencyPerSec
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t
 ORDER BY
 s.max_elapsed_time DESC
 GO
```

[source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/02/sql-server-2008-2005-find-longest-running-query-tsql/)

The magic here is you can find out which commands take up the most time overall, regardless if it's a command being ran 10 times extremely slowly, or a command running 1,000,000 times but very fast.

You may also get away with something a little higher-up as well. I've been able to debug projects previously by attaching a profiler to the beginning and end of each of my web requests, but then again that's not going to find the specific command that's causing the problem.